# Using JS to render Django form

Tags: javascript, django

I'm learning to utilize pure JS in Django projects. Being a server-side developer  the concepts are relatively new for me, so need a hand.

Imagine a form where a user can post text, and/or upload an image. Think of it as a simple Django form like so:

```
class PostForm(forms.Form):
    image = forms.ImageField(required=False)
    reply = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols':30,'rows':3,'class': 'cxl','autocomplete': 'off','autofocus': 'autofocus'}))

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(PostForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['image'].widget.attrs['id'] = 'browse_image_btn'

    def clean(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data
        # perform cleaning
        return data
```

If I were to render this form in HTML, something like the following would do:

```
<form action="{% url 'post_content' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ post_form.reply }}<br>
    {{ post_form.image }}
    <label for="browse_image_btn" style="cursor: pointer;"><img alt="Select photo" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}img/upload.svg" width="70" height="70"></label>        
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

But how do I create this HTML solely via JS?

**Use-case:** imagine a page that contains a long list of content, with a `reply` button under each. The form above only appears under specific content once the user has pressed the `reply` button. Moreover, pressing the same button toggles it `off` too.

I can't seem to wrap my head around solving a problem like that. Please advise, preferably with an illustrative example. I'd prefer to understand the most efficient, scalable way to do this, one that can be deployed in professional settings. Only pure JS, no JQuery.

---

I've made attempts at this, but they're half-baked since I'm a JS newbie. Here's what I've got so far:

```
  var okBtn = document.createElement('button');
    setUpSubmitBtn(okBtn);
   e.target.parentNode.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', okBtn);

   var camBtn = document.createElement('img');
    setUpCameraBtn(camBtn);
   e.target.parentNode.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', lineBreak);
   e.target.parentNode.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', camBtn);

   var replyBox = document.createElement('textarea');
    setUpReplyBox(replyBox);
   e.target.parentNode.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', replyBox);
```

Where there are simple JS functions to create each of the widgets referred above:

```
function setUpReplyBox(replyBox) {
    replyBox.classList.add('mts');
    replyBox.setAttribute('id', 'reply-message');
    replyBox.setAttribute('style', 'display:inline');
    replyBox.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Reply');
}

function setUpSubmitBtn(okBtn) {
    okBtn.classList.add('btn', 'bcb', 'bs', 'mts');
    okBtn.setAttribute('style','border:none;height:25px;display:inline;');
    okBtn.setAttribute('id','reply-ok');
    okBtn.innerHTML = "OK";
}

function setUpCameraBtn(camBtn) {
    camBtn.setAttribute('id','camera');
    camBtn.setAttribute('src','/static/img/cam1.svg');
    camBtn.setAttribute('width','45');
    camBtn.setAttribute('height','45');
    camBtn.setAttribute('style','display:inline;float:right;');
}
```

I feel like I'm doing it the hard/wrong way. The right pattern is probably going to be much simpler.

Comment: Just render all forms with display none and toggle them with js or render one and move it with js (change id dynamicly)

Comment: @bigless: I was just wondering if rendering all forms with display:none, would work. I like your 2nd suggestion even more; regarding rendering one and moving it with JS. But how would that work? Would I do `position: absolute;
   top: -9999px;
   left: -9999px;`, and then move it in place with JS? It would be great to get a quick starter example from you on this subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope it helps:

```js
var formTemplate = document.querySelector('#form-template form');
var idInput = document.getElementById('id-input');

function toggleReply(e) {
  if (!formTemplate) return;

  e.target.parentNode.insertBefore(formTemplate, e.target);
  idInput.value = e.target.getAttribute('data-id');
};

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('button.reply'))
  .forEach(btn => btn.onclick = toggleReply)
```

```css
form + .reply {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="form-template" style="display: none;">
  <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input id="id-input" type="hidden" name="id" value="">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="reply">Reply:</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" type="text" name="text"></textarea>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-right" value="submit">
  </form>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="list-group">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Comment title</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        Comment content
      </div>
      <div class="panel-footer clearfix">
        <button class="reply btn btn-default pull-right" type="button" data-id="24">Reply</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Comment title</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        Comment content
      </div>
      <div class="panel-footer clearfix">
        <button class="reply btn btn-default pull-right" type="button" data-id="25">Reply</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm going through this. One thing though: the exercise I'm doing is pure JS, not JQuery. Could you change the JQuery code to JS instead?

Comment: @HassanBaig updated but remember  that manupulating DOM with vanilla could be real pain.

Comment: Thanks for that. As a learning goal, I was thinking I'd learn pure JS concepts and then move onto the more powerful JQuery. However, there's quite a buzz around me re: React.JS. What would be your advice regarding which library to get accustomed to for someone who wants to improve their client-side chops?

Comment: @HassanBaig Note that I am not fun of jQuery but if you want dynamic frontend without rewriting backend, its fastest way. I dont know ReactJS but guess its frontend mvc same as angular. Its good for sites where are expected many user interactions like admins etc. Con is need to write restapi.

Comment: The form kept within the `div` with id `form-template` is inserted in a different location once a reply button is pressed. If a second reply button is pressed, this same form moves again. However, by then, that form wasn't inside the `div` with id `form-template` any more (it had already moved once). Then how on earth does  `var formTemplate = document.querySelector('#form-template form');` get populated correctly every time? I thought `#form-template form` meant **select the form inside the element with id form-template**. Would love to get some explanation regarding that added to your answer

Comment: @HassanBaig formTemplate is reference to node. It is not value, but reference to object. If you want preserve original node, you have to use clone()

Comment: cloneNode() in case of vanilla

Comment: Struggling with one aspect of your solution, and ended up writing a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48491006/4936905 If interested re: what that is, do check it out!