# Moving HTML form from one location to another (and back) via pure JS

Tags: javascript

I'm a server-side dev (primarily Pythong/Django) but am now learning pure Javascript. The concepts are relatively new for me, so need a hand.

Imagine a web app where users can post content (text or images). All posts appear on a single page as a long list. Under each post, there's a `reply` button. Pressing it dynamically creates (via JS) a form-field used to reply to the said post.

There's also an added requirement.

Pressing that same `reply` button *again* should disappear the previously created form. Essentially, the `reply` button toggles the form on and off.

Moreover, if any other posts in the page also had a form, that should disappear also.

I've been able to accomplish all of the above, but need help with toggling **off** the form once it's 'on' (at the same spot). That is my question.

---

Currently, upon page load, I park the code form's code at the top of the HTML page, inside a `div` with `display:none`.

Whenever a `reply` button is pressed under a post, I move this form under that same post. If an entirely different `reply` button is pressed thereafter, the form moves once again, to that new location.

Like I said, the one thing I can't seem to do is toggling the form on and off when the same reply button is repeatedly pressed.

Ideally, I don't want to change the strategy I'm using (it has worked well for me), but will change it for efficiency reasons (a big plus for me). Secondly I'm looking for pure JS solutions. JQuery is on my radar, but I want to gain an understanding of JS first, hence this requirement.

---

My JS code currently is:

```
var formTemplate = document.querySelector('#form-template form');

function createInput(payload, id) {
    // populating input fields with correct values
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('id',id);
    input.setAttribute('type','hidden');
    input.setAttribute('value',payload);    
    return(input);
   }

function toggleReply(e) {
  if (!formTemplate) return;

  // prevent form submission
  e.preventDefault();

  // moving 'ghost form' into position
  e.target.parentNode.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', formTemplate);

  // getting pertinent values from "reply" button
  var payload = e.target.parentNode.querySelector('#payload').value;
  payload = payload.split(':');
  var tt = payload[5];
  var bid = payload[0];
  var idx = payload[3];

  // assigning populated input fields to form 
  formTemplate.appendChild(createInput(tt, 'tt'));
  formTemplate.appendChild(createInput(bid, 'bid'));
  formTemplate.appendChild(createInput(idx, 'idx'));

  }
};

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('button.rep'))
.forEach(btn => btn.onclick = toggleReply)
```

The form parked at the very start of the HTML document looks like so:

```
<div id="form-template" style="display: none;">
    <form action="{% url 'reply_to_post' %}" id="rep-form" method="POST" style="display:inline" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {% csrf_token %}

        <div style="width:75%;display:inline-block;">
            {{ personal_group_form.reply }}
        </div>

        <div style="width:22%;display:inline-block;float:right;text-align:center;">
            {{ personal_group_form.image }}
            <label for="browse_image_btn" style="cursor: pointer;"><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}img/cam1.svg" width="70" height="70" /></label>
        </div>

        <button style="border:none;height:30px;" name="tid" value="{{ tid }}" type="submit">OK</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Ignore the `{%` or `{{` type syntax. That's Django.

Finally, the reply buttons under each post of content are laid out like:

```
<form action="{% url 'post_buttons' %}" method="POST" style="display:inline">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <input id="payload" type="hidden" name="pl" value="{{ blob_id }}:{{ username }}:{{ score }}:{{ idx }}:{{ t }}:{{ tt }}:{{ tid }}:{{ img_width }}:{{ their_nick }}:{{ own_nick }}:{{ is_res }}:{{ av_url }}">

   <button type="submit" class="rep" name="dec" value="1">reply</button>
   <button type="submit" name="dec" value="2">save</button>
   <button type="submit" name="dec" value="3">hide</button>

</form>
```

Finally, I've tried tweaking my previously posted JS code as below, but it hasn't given me the correct result:

```
var formTemplate = document.querySelector('#form-template form');

function createInput(name, payload, id) {
    // populating input fields with correct values
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('id',id);
    input.setAttribute('type','hidden');
    input.setAttribute('name',name);    
    input.setAttribute('value',payload);    
    return(input);
}

function toggleReply(e) {
  // error-handling the case where there is no ghost form
  if (!formTemplate) return;

  // prevent form submission
  e.preventDefault();

  // first check if reply form was already added under reply button
  var to_remove = e.target.parentNode.nextSibling.querySelector("#rep-form");

  if (to_remove != null) {

      // move form back to being a ghost (it was already added under the reply button)
      document.querySelector('#form-template').insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin',formTemplate);

  } else {

      // moving ghost form into position
      e.target.parentNode.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', formTemplate);

      // getting value from "reply" button
      var payload = e.target.parentNode.querySelector('#payload').value;
      payload = payload.split(':');
      var tt = payload[5];
      var bid = payload[0];
      var idx = payload[3];

      // assigning populated input fields to formTemplate 
      formTemplate.appendChild(createInput('', tt, 'tt'));
      formTemplate.appendChild(createInput('', bid, 'bid'));
      formTemplate.appendChild(createInput('', idx, 'idx'));

  }
};

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('button.rep'))
  .forEach(btn => btn.onclick = toggleReply)
```

I get `TypeError: e.target.parentNode.nextSibling.querySelector is not a function`. Changing to `e.target.parentNode.nextSibling.getElementById()` doesn't work either. In fact, even just printing the value of `e.target.parentNode.nextSibling` yields erroneous results. Please advise.

Comment: Why not just put `display: none` back on the form to hide it?

Comment: @BenWest: Do you mean this: 1) I keep the template form parked at the top with `style=display:none`. 2) When a reply button is pressed, I move the form to the designated place, and remove the `display:none` attribute. 3) If the same button is pressed again, I reinsert `display:none` to disappear the form. 4) If a new `reply` button is pressed somewhere else, I simply move this form there, populating it with the new values required. *Is this the flow in your mind*? If so, I'm actually having trouble pulling off **3** even if I use this pattern.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm thinking.

Comment: Yea..when I was talking about "vanilla real pain", this is exactly that case and thats why jQuery exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manipulating DOM elements via pure JS is not trivial. I ended up handling the myriad edge cases manually, with the code being:

```
var formTemplate = document.querySelector('#form-template');

function createInput(name, payload) {
    // populating input fields with correct values
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('type','hidden');
    input.setAttribute('id',name);
    input.setAttribute('name',name);    
    input.setAttribute('value',payload);    
    return(input);
}

function removeInputFields() {
    // remove unneeded input fields
    child1 = document.getElementById('tt');
    child2 = document.getElementById('bid');
    child3 = document.getElementById('idx');
    if (child1 != null) { formTemplate.removeChild(child1); }
    if (child2 != null) { formTemplate.removeChild(child2); }
    if (child3 != null) { formTemplate.removeChild(child3); }
}

function appendInputFields(payload) {

    // getting value from "reply" button
    payload = payload.split(':');
    var tt = payload[5];
    var bid = payload[0];
    var idx = payload[3];

    // assigning populated input fields to formTemplate 
    formTemplate.appendChild(createInput('tt', tt));
    formTemplate.appendChild(createInput('bid', bid));
    formTemplate.appendChild(createInput('idx', idx));

}

function toggleReply(e) {

  // error-handling the case where there is no ghost form
  if (!formTemplate) return;

  // prevent form submission
  e.preventDefault();

  // first check if reply form was already added under reply button
  var to_remove = this.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
  console.log(to_remove);
  if (to_remove == null) {

      // make the form visible
      formTemplate.style.display = 'inline';

      // remove unneeded input fields
      removeInputFields();

      // moving ghost form into position
      e.target.parentNode.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', formTemplate);

      // creating and appending desired input fields in formTemplate
      appendInputFields(e.target.parentNode.querySelector('#payload').value);

  }

   if (to_remove != null && to_remove.id == 'form-template') {
      console.log(formTemplate.style.display);
      // toggle form visibility
      if ( formTemplate.style.display == 'inline' ) { 
        formTemplate.style.display = 'none';

        // remove unneeded input fields
        removeInputFields();
      }
      else {
        formTemplate.style.display = 'inline';

        // remove unneeded input fields
        removeInputFields();

        // moving ghost form into position
        e.target.parentNode.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', formTemplate);

        // creating and appending desired input fields in formTemplate
        appendInputFields(e.target.parentNode.querySelector('#payload').value);
      }



  } else {

      // make the form visible
      formTemplate.style.display = 'inline';

      // remove unneeded input fields
      removeInputFields();

      // moving ghost form into position
      e.target.parentNode.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', formTemplate);

      // creating and appending desired input fields in formTemplate
      appendInputFields(e.target.parentNode.querySelector('#payload').value);

  }

};

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('button.rep'))
  .forEach(btn => btn.onclick = toggleReply)
```

It's ugly and longish, but gets the job done. Hopefully there's room for optimization here.

Answer (score 1):

Moving this one form around is making things complicated. Why not give each post its own form and then just toggle them with `display`?

```
var form = e.target.parentNode.querySelector('form');
form.style.display = form.style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
```

Comment: There was a mistake before (`isHidden = false`) in both branches, that's fixed now.

Comment: Why can't each post have its own form which toggles? Moving this one form around the page is making things complicated.

Comment: Yes makes it complicated, but the tradeoff is network transfer. As the amount of content scales, a page with endless scroll will have a ton of forms with `display:none`, inflating the file size of the KBs transferred, hitting your AWS bill at the end of the month. But if we move around one form, it swaps that network transfer for the client's computing power. You code it (with pain) once, you reap the benefits forever. That's my reasoning. But you're right, much more painless to have a *ghost* form with each reply.

Comment: Doesn't sound worth it to me. The form HTML will be absolutely tiny compared to other things on your site, like images.

Comment: True the gains will indeed be trivial for a smallish app. Let's explore it this way, and if push comes to shove, we'll make our lives easier. Your current method works, except once the form appears under a post, if I press the `reply` button under a different post, it doesn't jump to that location (which it did in my original code). Instead, it just closed in the original position (and one has to press the `reply` button a second time to get it there).